# AngularJS $httpprovider.interceptors.push is not working

Tags: angularjs, authentication, inspector

I have a angular JS factory method in inspect.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("Myapp")
         .factory("MyAppAuthIn", ['$window', '$q', function ($window, $q) {
             var authFactory = {};
             var _request = function (config) {
                 config.headers = config.headers || {};
                 var authData = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
                 if (accessToken) {
                     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData;
                 }
                 return config;
             }

             var _responseError = function (rejection) {
                 if (rejection.status === 401) {
                     console.log("Some Error Here");
                 }
                 return $q.reject(rejection);
             }

             authFactory.request = _request;
             authFactory.responseError = _responseError;
             return authFactory;
         }]);
});
```

And i have the module in appModule.js file here it is.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("Myapp")
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyAppAuthIn');
            
        });
}());
```

I included both the JS files into my ASPX page and run. Then I get error message says

> > Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MyAppAuthInProvider <- MyAppAuthIn<- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

But If i make all in one file like myspector.js is working fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("Myapp", [])
        .factory("MyAppAuthIn", ['$window', '$q', function ($window, $q) {
             var authFactory = {};
             var _request = function (config) {
                 config.headers = config.headers || {};
                 var authData = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
                 if (accessToken) {
                     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData;
                 }
                 return config;
             }

             var _responseError = function (rejection) {
                 if (rejection.status === 401) {
                     console.log("Some Error Here");
                 }
                 return $q.reject(rejection);
             }

             authFactory.request = _request;
             authFactory.responseError = _responseError;
             return authFactory;
         }])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyAppAuthIn');
        }]);

}());
```

Can anyone help me to understand the issue?.. i'm almost 2 days now to troubleshoot this issue. Please help highly appreciated

Comment: I think you just need to inject your factory definition into your module.  It works when they're in the same file because the factory is still in scope.

Comment: @twodave not accurate, using `angular.module("Myapp")` without a dependency array argument is not declaring a new module ... it is referencing an existing one

Comment: so your proposal is to inject my factory into module, something like app.config(function ($httpProvider,MyAppAuthIn) { $httpProvider.interceptors.push(MyAppAuthIn);}
??

Comment: @charlietfl If that is the case then I don't see why the example wouldn't work without injecting the factory. It could just be a simple matter of re-ordering his script tags...

Comment: Can any of you guys given me the sample code out of this code?. I'm sorry, i'm pretty new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Your call to `angular.module()` in appModule.js needs a dependency list (even if it's empty).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("Myapp", [])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyAppAuthIn');
            
        });
}());
```

See plnkr for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpCKl1zO4sbt605VgrCF

Comment: Here's a valuable piece of information: if you defined your interceptors in a different module than the app's main module then you have to register them in THE SAME MODULE'S CONFIG PHASE. Learned that the hard way.